# CreateView Expose Filter Block

Tags: views

I have create a view and expose 3 filter but I want to create a expose block only one filter.
I have expose title,post date,and global search. but how to create only block of title in view.

when I create block of title then all three expose filter block has been created.

Comment: use override option

Comment: Stop duplicating this question.